# Add record to MS Access table fails - wrong auto id value

Tags: ms-access-2013

I need to add records to  a table which has a unique id field. Up until recently I did this via a query but find today it doesn't work.

I tried manually copying a record and I tried manually inputting a new record. In both cases Access created a record with id=1306 but the next id would have been 1899. Consequently there was an error msg = The changes you made were not successful because they would create duplicate id...

Every time I go through this process the trial id clocks on 1 and is now 1309.
I am prevented from editing this manually. The table is related to many other tables and vice versa.

Any ideas please.
The table was created under Access 2003 or earlier. The edition running now is 2013.
Thanks - Stewart.

Comment: Try a **Repair & Compact**. Or look here: [Alllen Browne: Fixing AutoNumbers when Access assigns negatives or duplicates](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html)

Comment: Thanks. I backed up the db, then ran  Repair and Compact, which was instantaneous, then tested it and it worked. I am grateful for this.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by running **Repair & Compact**.

Wrong/duplicate generated Autonumbers are a sign that something is broken in the database.

Further reading:
[Allen Browne: Fixing AutoNumbers when Access assigns negatives or duplicates](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html)